# Setting Up Postgres for the first time in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, php, postgresql, intellij-idea

Ok so I am currently trying to set up a Postgres Database on IntelliJ and I'm running into an issue. I was going through the settings trying to understand the different configurations and get a better understanding of what was going on as I've never dealt with any kind of SQL related databases before. Not to my knowledge at least. When I click on the schema tab, this prompt shows up:

`The specified user/password combination is rejected: [08004] The server requested password-based authentication, but no password was provided.`

This is followed by a prompt asking for a username & password. I entered `root` (literally) in the username section, and a made up `password` in the password section, and I got this error message:

`The specified user/password combination is rejected: [28P01] FATAL: password authentication failed for user "root"`.

I am not sure what I am supposed to do as I was never asked to set up a password. From what I get from the prompt, a username seems to have already been defined by IntelliJ. How do I find out what that `username` is and reset the `password`? And if that's not the way to go, how should I go about solving this issue?

EDIT: I finally figured it out. The username had to be the same as the name of my database. From then I was able to set up my password, and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Change in the PostgreSQL config file pg_hba.conf parameter for authentication method for IPv4 local connections to 'trust' instead 'md5' or 'peer':

## IPv4 local connections:

## host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust

And then, you have to restart your postgresql-server with command - 'sudo service postgresql restart' - it helped for me with the same issue. Sorry for the bad markup, because I'm new here on stackoverflow.

Comment: Which parameter did you change?

Comment: Just parameter for authentication method for IPv4 local connections to 'trust' instead 'md5' or 'peer'.

Comment: If you want to add this to your answer, please add this to your answer. These lines do not look like comments. And please don't add irrelevant images if you could better add the content as text

Answer (score 0):

What did you do while the installation of pg ?
I remember that default values are root:root for login credentials 
Did you try to connect yourself on your db using pg as command line ?

Comment: No I didn't. Figured everything would be integrated within intellij. How do I connect using the command line??

Also I technically haven't created the database yet since it's not allowing me to without setting a password. My issue happens while going through the settings before confirming the creation of the database.